# C# binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have implemented a basic data binding in code behind, this is the code:

```
Binding bindingSlider = new Binding();
bindingSlider.Source = mediaElement.Position;
bindingSlider.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;            
bindingSlider.Converter = (IValueConverter)Application.Current.Resources["DoubleTimeSpan"];            
slider.SetBinding(Slider.ValueProperty, bindingSlider);
```

And this is the converter's code,

```
class DoubleTimeSpan : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
string language)
    {
        return ((TimeSpan)value).TotalSeconds;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
string language)
    {           
        return TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)value);
    }
}
```

Even though I don't receive compiler's error message, but the binding code is not working. Why?

Comment: Take a look in the output window and see if any errors are reported there.

Comment: Check the output windows because we don't know what's your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bindingSlider.Source = mediaElement.Position ; // boo!
```

This is wrong. `Source` is the object containing the property you are binding to. What you want is

```
bindingSlider.Source = mediaElement ;
bindingSlider.Path   = new PropertyPath ("Position") ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it's working smoothly now. Learn new things at here everyday.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `Path` property instead of `Source` in data binding.

Answer (score 0):

It is a quite difficult to get from your code what is wrong. As Fabian said - check output windows. But increase binding trace level before. Check next to know how to do it.

[PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.tracelevel.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the Source you are binding to is a `UIElement`, try this :

```
Binding bindingSlider = new Binding("Position");
bindingSlider.ElementName = "mediaElement";
bindingSlider.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;            
bindingSlider.Converter = (IValueConverter)Application.Current.Resources["DoubleTimeSpan"];            
slider.SetBinding(Slider.ValueProperty, bindingSlider);
```